# Unable to access set within set | C++

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have a class named "Store", it has 2 data fields of type "set": "customers" (of type std::set) and "albums" (of type `std::set<Album>`).

```
std::set<Album> albums;
std::set<Customer> customers;
```

Now, when I try to save data to one of those sets - everything works fine , but in the type "Customer" I have a third set named orders ( of type std::set ), and when I try to save data to it (and after I leave the function that saves the data) it disappears!

here is how I save the data to it:

```
Customer foundCustomer = *Customer::findID(customers ,id);

Order newOrder = Order();
newOrder.ordNum = ordNum;
newOrder.isPaid = false;

foundCustomer.orders.insert(newOrder);
```

tell me if you need me to post more code.

Help would be much appreciated !

Comment: What's the function `findID()` exactly ? The problem might be related to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer foundCustomer = *Customer::findID(customers ,id);
```

This line makes a copy of the customer. If you want to modify the original customer int he set, you would need to use a reference:

```
Customer& foundCustomer = *Customer::findID(customers ,id);
```

And make sure that `*Customer::findID(...)` results in a reference as well.

Comment: Except you can't modify the elements of a set.